# How can I multiply a result by a specific value from another table?

Tags: mysql

A simplification of my problem. Say I have these tables:

Supply:

- supplyName: VARCHAR(20), Just the name of an office supply. Say pens.
- quantityPerBox: INT, the number of the supply that comes in a box.

Boxes:

- supplyName: VARCHAR(20), Name of a supply, references the Supply table.
- numBoxes: INT, the number of boxes of the supply.

Basically want I want to do is:

```
SELECT supplyName, numberOfSupply GROUP BY supplyName
```

from these tables. But I want numberOfSupply to be quantityPerBox*numBoxes.

Can this be done as a query? Or would I need to store the quantities from the Supply table in a program in some language (PHP for instance) and do the calculations there? (Or is there really no benefit from doing the calculation as part of the query, even if it's possible?)

Thank you for your help in advance. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This can certainly be done in a query without having to store that value separately, or using a different language:

```
SELECT s.supplyName, s.quantityPerBox * b.numBoxes AS NumberOfSupply
FROM Supply AS s
INNER JOIN Boxes AS b ON s.supplyName = b.supplyName
```

You probably want to add `SupplyId` to both tables though so you have an integer value to `JOIN` on: more efficient than trying to `JOIN` on a `VARCHAR` field.  Another benefit is that  if you ever wanted to change the `supplyName` of an item, you would not have to worry about foreign key issues when making that change if you were referencing tables by ID instead of a value within the table.

Comment: Ah, I see now. As usual, I was overthinking it. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I've got it working.